# Searching employees by name shows all rows (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure with a parameter @name nvarchar(50).
Now the stored procedure itself looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]
    @empName nvarchar   
AS
    SELECT 
        employee_id AS 'ID',
        name_1+' '+surname AS 'NAME'    
    FROM 
        Employees
    WHERE   
        'NAME' LIKE '%'+@empName+'%'
```

I enter any part of a name that exists in the table, but, as a result, I get the whole table. Sometimes I get strange results, e.g. two rows, one of which matches criteria, the other one doesn't.

Comment: Post the entire stored procedure and the way that you are calling it. If `@name` was blank, that would explain why you get every record.

Comment: Please note: The error is clear in this example. Post all the code first time. Anything you leave out just confuses people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]

    @empName NVARCHAR(500)   

AS BEGIN

    SELECT 
          ID = e.employee_id
        , NAME = e.name_1 + ' ' + e.surname    
    FROM dbo.Employees e
    WHERE e.name_1 + ' ' + e.surname LIKE '%'+ @empName + '%'

END
```

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]

    @empName NVARCHAR(500)   

AS BEGIN

    SELECT 
          e2.ID
        , e2.NAME
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              ID = e.employee_id
            , NAME = e.name_1 + ' ' + e.surname -- + ' ' + e.first_name + ....  
        FROM dbo.Employees e
    ) e2
    WHERE e2.NAME LIKE '%'+ @empName + '%'

END
```

Comment: Vladimir, there is no any secrets, just one note - you was comparing two literals in WHERE filter. In your query you need to compare field's values with literal.

Comment: Please see the updated example. I guess in this case, square brackets are not needed. It depends on what kind of data is stored in the variable. The Damith example is quite workable in case  @empName contains only a name or surname. In my example it's not important since the string contains both a name and surname.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    emp_id AS ID, 
    emp_name+' '+ emp_surname AS NAME
FROM 
    Employees 
WHERE 
    emp_name LIKE '%' + @name+ '%' OR  emp_surname LIKE '%' + @name+ '%'
```